# Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue does not add any errors to $Error variable

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am trying to figure out why when I set ErrorAction to SilentlyContinue, no errors are written to the $Error variable.

This is the command I am using:
`Import-CSV C:\Users\User\Documents\list.csv | foreach{Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity mydladdress@mysite.com -Member $_.email -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}`.

When I run the command without the ErrorAction, the errors are printed to the $Error variable but it also displays the errors in the console which I do not want.

Your assistance will be appreciated!

Kind regards,
Dust

Comment: It may be a different stream.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: While this question is now more focused, it is still a duplicate of your earlier one. `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` _normally_ does _not_ prevent non-terminating errors from getting recorded in `$Error`. If this really happens with `Remove-DistributionGroupMember`, specifically, it would  be a bug, though I'd be surprised, given that this `-ErrorAction` is a so-called [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters), meaning that it is implemented by the PowerShell engine itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The command posted definitely does not write to the $Error variable. I have multiple other scripts that work fine using the same structure so I think this may be a bug related to the Remove-DistributionGroupMemeber as you've suggested. I'll have to look into handling the errors a different way or just deal with them being written to the console. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can also try to capture the errors via `-ErrorVariable errs`, for instance (I've updated the answer to the linked post) - though if `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` truly doesn't work, I wouldn't be too hopeful. I encourage you to post an answer of your own to your original question if you get to the bottom of this. Food for thought: is there something unusual about your environment? E.g., are you using a module with _implicitly remoting_?